# issue in one2many write

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo-10

In the below code i have get a 2 rows as a result. then i create the object by using the results. Then i assign the created values in to the one2many field (inventory_line) . but here only one row has displayed. i want to list out the all created vales in the one2many..? how can i fix this issue..?

```
@api.multi
def _inventory(self):
    result = {}
    if not self: return result
    print ("Trueeeeeeeeeeeeee")


    inventory_obj = self.env['tpt.product.inventory']
    print (inventory_obj,"inventory_obj")
    for id in self:
        print (id,"id")
        result.setdefault(id, [])
        sql = 'delete from tpt_product_inventory where product_id=%s'%(id.id)
        print (sql,"sql")
        self._cr.execute(sql)


        sql = '''
            select foo.loc,foo.prodlot_id,foo.id as uom,sum(foo.product_qty) as ton_sl, foo.product_id from 
               (select l2.id as loc,st.prodlot_id,pu.id,st.product_qty,st.product_id
                   from stock_move st 
                       inner join stock_location l2 on st.location_dest_id= l2.id
                       inner join product_uom pu on st.product_uom = pu.id
                   where st.state='done' and st.product_id=%s and l2.usage = 'internal'
               union all
               select l1.id as loc,st.prodlot_id,pu.id,st.product_qty*-1, st.product_id
                   from stock_move st 
                       inner join stock_location l1 on st.location_id= l1.id
                       inner join product_uom pu on st.product_uom = pu.id
                   where st.state='done' and st.product_id=%s and l1.usage = 'internal'
               )foo
               group by foo.loc,foo.prodlot_id,foo.id, foo.product_id
        '''%(id.id,id.id)
        self._cr.execute(sql)
```

})

```
 for inventory in self._cr.dictfetchall():
            print (inventory,"inventory")
            new_id = inventory_obj.create( {'warehouse_id':inventory['loc'],'product_id':inventory['product_id'],'prodlot_id':inventory['prodlot_id'],'hand_quantity':inventory['ton_sl'],'uom_id':inventory['uom']})
            print (new_id,"new_id")
            self.inventory_line = new_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you better create an SQL View for this scenario and associate it with the model `tpt.product.inventory` and you could remove all of the code you are using to match the records(delete and create the new ones)

You could find a very similar example here:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/695050dd10e786d7b316f6e7e40418441cf0c8dd/addons/stock/report/report_stock_forecast.py